# Undefined property: stdClass::$etiqueta

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Buenas tardes estoy intentando conectar dos tablas relacionadas pero sin éxito. Tengo dos tablas pero una de ellas no está en las migraciones pero si tiene su modelo.

**Mi tabla de vivienda**

| id | name | etiqueta_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nombre1 | 2 |
| 2 | nombre2 | 4 |

**Mi tabla de etiquetas**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Rebajado |
| 2 | Oportunidad |

**Modelo Vivienda -** Este es el que no está en las migraciones
Como una vivienda solo puede tener una etiqueta, le pongo `belongsTo`.

```
    protected $primaryKey='id'; 
    protected $table = 'vivienda';

    public function etiqueta()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Etiqueta', 'id');
    }
```

**Modelo Etiqueta -**
Como una etiqueta puede pertenecer a más de una vivienda le pongo, le pongo `hasMany`.

```
    protected $primaryKey='id'; 
    protected $table = 'etiquetas';

    public function vivienda()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vivienda', 'etiqueta_id');
    }
```

**Controlador**

```
$viviendas = DB::table('vivienda')->where('tipo_id', 1)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('home', 1)->where('conectado', 1)->limit(4)->get();
```

**Cuando itero las viviendas**

```
@foreach ($viviendas as $item)
   ......
   /*Intento acceder así*/
   {{ $item->etiqueta->name }}
@endforeach
```

Pero me devuelve este error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$etiqueta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta sintaxis:

```
$item->etiqueta->name
```

No te va a funcionar con la query actual debido a que:

- Etiqueta no existe en el conjunto de resultados de la tabla `viviendas`, (*solo la llave foránea como vínculo con la otra tabla*)
- Tratas de acceder a la relación `etiqueta` pero por medio de una query definida con ayuda del *facade* `DB`, deberías usar el modelo y cargar a su vez sus relaciones con ayuda de [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)
- Si no deseas llevarlo a cabo como indico en el paso anterior, entonces deberás emplear un *`join`*

Luego entonces si te decides por el punto 2 sería así:

```
$viviendas = Vivienda::query()
                     ->with('etiqueta')
                     ->where('tipo_id', 1)
                     ->where('home', 1)
                     ->where('conectado', 1)
                     ->limit(4)
                     ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                     ->get();
```

Además de lo anterior, considera que como indica [la propia documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) el segundo argumento del método `belongsTo()` debe ser la llave foránea que en este caso sería `etiqueta_id`, **recomiendo repases los enlaces a detalle para que identifiques cuando se deben o no pasar argumentos extra.**

Quedando así:

```
->belongsTo(Etiqueta::class, 'etiqueta_id');
```

Finalmente:

- Considera que si vas a implementar las relaciones de Eloquent, entonces deberás usar los modelos, sugiero [repases la doc. al respecto](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)